# Does the caster of the Incendiary Cloud spell choose the direction it moves only when it's cast, or choose it every turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

The Sorcerer & Wizard spell [*incendiary cloud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/incendiary-cloud) moves away from the caster at the start of each turn:

> The cloud moves 10 feet directly away from you in a direction that you choose at the start of each of your turns.

**Does the caster choose the direction at the time of the casting? Or can they choose a new direction every turn?**

---

A Q&A that's somewhat related: [In what direction does the area of the Incendiary Cloud spell move at the start of the caster's turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100602/in-what-direction-does-the-area-of-the-incendiary-cloud-spell-move-at-the-start)

However, that question asks specifically about the direction in which the cloud moves - not whether the direction can change from turn to turn. As such, it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Every turn

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, the answer is in the phrase you quoted.

As you've quoted, the description of [*incendiary cloud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/incendiary-cloud) says (emphasis mine):

> [...] a direction that you **choose** at the start of **each** of your turns.

- Round 1, the caster casts *incendiary cloud* on their turn. It stays put for the time being.
- Round 2, at the start of the caster's next turn, they choose a direction.<sup>1</sup> At the end of that turn, the cloud settles into place 10 feet away from its starting point. <sup>2</sup>
- Round 3, on the beginning of the caster's turn, the caster can choose again.

Each turn, the player starts by declaring a direction. Nothing says it has to be the same direction as last time.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm confused about how the cloud moves "directly away" **and** in a direction that is chosen, but that's outside the scope of the question. This is about when and how often.

<sup>2</sup> Mechanically, the cloud moves to the chosen spot 10 ft away. Narratively, it is up to the DM to decide if the cloud moves either instantly or over the course of the caster's turn.

Comment: I'm confused at your specification of timing. You say the caster chooses the direction the AoE moves at the start of their next turn, but claim that the cloud only moves "at the end of round 2", and then the caster chooses again "at the beginning of round 3". However, that's not what the spell description says; it says that the AoE "moves [...] in a direction that you choose at the start of each of your turns". Nothing in the spell description says it moves at any other time other than when you make the choice (i.e. you choose the direction it moves at the time that it moves).

Comment: @V2Blast, not sure when the confusion is. At the start of round two, the caster says, "Move X direction". And when it has reached it's new location, it "settles into place". I didn't say it moved at the end of the turn, I'm saying it moved and has come to rest by the end of the turn. Some may play that it creeps along while the caster does other actions, others that it happens instantaneously. The key is the caster chooses at the start, and it's presumed at rest at the end of the caster's turn.

Comment: @MivaScott: My point is that the caster doesn't choose the direction "at the start of round 2" (i.e. after everyone has taken their turn in the first full round of initiative, just before the second round of initiative starts); they choose it at the start of *their turn*, which could be anywhere in the turn order.

Comment: ...And nothing in the spell description says it gradually moves over the course of the round - mechanically, it moves instantaneously at the start of the caster's turn (though this might seem strange *narratively*), with no period specified over which it "settles into place". (Different DMs may narrate this in different ways, but it doesn't affect how the spell works mechanically within the turn order by RAW.)

Comment: @V2Blast, I rewrote the answer in a way that I hope is clearer. Took some of the comments into the answer also.